# Кто-то отбрасывает тень, а кто-то нет

Tags: дефект, дизайн

Вот тут https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users?page=2&tab=reputation&filter=month для изображений пользователей применяются различные правила для отрисовывания тени. Это дефект или так задумано?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Да это вампиры так обозначаются.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Так задумано. Тень указывает, что карточка этого участника разворачивается, если на неё навести мышкой. Чтобы получить это, нужно иметь 1000 очков и не очень короткую биографию.

См. привилегию ["Постоянный Пользователь"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user)